# How to buy and sell Ardor

Tags: trading, ardor

I know this community is for bitcoin but I couldn't find any community to talk about crypto-currencies in general so I thought this may be the right place to ask.

I am interested on investing money on Ardor but I am kind of new in the world of crypto-currencies. So if someone could explain me how to buy and then sell Ardor in an easy way and avoiding places that could end up like mt.gox that would be nice.

Comment: Hi Juan, you're in the right place. Per our community guidelines questions about all cryptocurrencies are on-topic (although Ethereum and Monero have created their own Stackexchange sites by now).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Poloniex is probably the best place to invest into Ardor.
Changelley (https://changelly.com) would be better if you don't want to keep the tokens on an exchange like Poloniex.

From the website:
Note: If you have ARDR tokens, do NOT send them to the address you create on the Ardor Testnet. Please send them to a Nxt Wallet from Nxt.org as ARDR is currently an asset on the Nxt blockchain until its launch in Q3.

Notice even the Ardor explorer is on Nxt:
https://www.mynxt.info/asset/12422608354438203866

Answer (score 2):

If you have bitcoins you can buy Ardor fastly and easily in Poloniex.
If not, you can buy Ardor with $ [here](https://changelly.com/exchange/USD/ARDR/1?ref_id=coinmarketcap)

Answer (score 1):

Coinmarketcap lists several markets, like Polo and BTC38:

https://coinmarketcap.com/assets/ardor/#markets

Answer (score 1):

In case you owned some BTC you can exchange it easily for Ardor in one of the exchanges who maintain BTC\ARDR market.
for example:

1. Poloniex.
2. Bittrex.

In case you don't own any BTC you need to buy some and then the above.

In general:
before trading you need a platform that will generate you Ardor private/public key so later you will be able to commit transaction - this pair can be stored  web exchanges, desktop client or else.

When this is done (you found way to store your tokens), you can search for exchange place who have a market Ardor\AnyKindOfValueYouWant and there you can start trade with users.

By market I don't mean only one of the listed above, it can on be even on instant msg platform such as Whatsapp, Telegram or Facebook group.

Comment: I think you probably mean Poloniex?